# How to print the contents from Devexpress ASP.Net Grid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, devexpress

[image]

**Question** How to include print option in Devexpress ASP.Net.
We unable to find out how to inherit print features using Devexpress ASP.Net Grid.

Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to use a separate ASPxGridViewExporter component for exporting ASPxGridView's content to the required output formats:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Exporting/Exporting.aspx